# removing selected variables in R environment

Tags: r

This is certainly a simple question but I can't find a solution.

I want to clean my environment by removing some variables I don't need anymore and keep some others.

I unterstand `ls()` can list them  and `ls()[[i]]` returns the name of the variable, as a string.

So If I want to remove the 10th, let's say it's the variable age , `ls()[[10]]` will return "age", and  I would like to do something like `rm(ls()[[10])`, but it does not work. I can't figure out to force `rm(ls([10]))` to be be equivalent to `rm(age)`.

I guess I need to force some evaluation of string "age" to return the variable age but can't find the proper function in R documentation.

Thanks if you can help.

Comment: Since you are using a character string for the object name, you want `rm(list=ls()[10])`.  It's explained in the docs for `help(rm)`

Comment: Thanks all for the info. That solves it. For the record, my objective was to remove maybe 90% of the variables. So I will go for a title loop based on the rank in ls(). Naming explicitly the variable to remove kind of defeats the purpose, which was to remove the not desired variables quickly, i.e without explicitly writing the names of the variables to remove.

Answer (score 3):

The `list` argument of `rm` will help you. It accepts a character vector. Consider:

```
age <- 1
rm(list = "age")  # Same effect as rm(age)
age
#Error: object 'age' not found
```

So running e.g.

```
rm(list = ls())
```

will clear *all* visible objects in the specified environment.

In your case `rm(list = ls()[10])` will do what you want. However, note that `ls()` always returns a sorted character vector, so the 10th entry can change rather easily. You probably want to do the following

```
objects_to_remove <- c("age", "another_object") # etc
rm(list = objects_to_remove)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the following:

1: Grab the list in the environment,

2: Define the items you want to remove,

3: Filter the list by the items you want to remove

4: Then remove them

```
    list <- ls()
    to_remove <- c("Item1", "Item2")
    list_to_remove <- list[ list %in% to_remove]
    list_to_remove

    rm(list=list_to_remove)
```